# android kotlin: error Value null at Scores of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

I am having a static JSON file which has an array which I am passing to Recycler view. For some attributes of JSON objects in the array are null which are causing this error

```
Value null at Geocode of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

(Geocode is not the only attribute which is null for some)

How can I resolve this error?

```
val outputJsonString = JSONObject(jsonData)

        val establishments = outputJsonString.getJSONObject("FHRSEstablishment")
            .getJSONArray("EstablishmentCollection") as JSONArray


        for(i in 0 until establishments.length()) {
            val geocode: JSONObject = establishments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Geocode")
            var longitude: String = ""
            var latitude: String = ""

            if(geocode != null) {
                longitude = geocode.getString("Longitude")
                latitude = geocode.getString("Latitude")
            }
            list.add(
                Restaurant(
                    establishments.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusinessName"),
                    establishments.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusinessType"),
                    establishments.getJSONObject(i).getString("RatingValue"),
                    establishments.getJSONObject(i).getString("LocalAuthorityName"),
                    arrayOf(
                        establishments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Scores").getString("Hygiene"),
                        establishments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Scores").getString("Structural"),
                        establishments.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Scores").getString("ConfidenceInManagement"),
                    ),
                    establishments.getJSONObject(i).getString("LocalAuthorityWebSite"),
                    longitude,
                    latitude
                )
            )
        }
```

Part of the JSON (each object is an element of the array)

```
{
        "FHRSID": 1332759,
        "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "21/00016/COM",
        "BusinessName": "54 Cake Lane",
        "BusinessType": "Other catering premises",
        "BusinessTypeID": 7841,
        "RatingValue": "Exempt",
        "RatingKey": "fhrs_exempt_en-GB",
        "RatingDate": null,
        "LocalAuthorityCode": "529",
        "LocalAuthorityName": "Sutton",
        "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.sutton.gov.uk",
        "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "food.safety@sutton.gov.uk",
        "Scores": null,
        "SchemeType": "FHRS",
        "NewRatingPending": false,
        "Geocode": null
      },
      {
        "FHRSID": 1530694,
        "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "22/00288/COM",
        "BusinessName": "66 Catering",
        "BusinessType": "Takeaway/sandwich shop",
        "BusinessTypeID": 7844,
        "AddressLine1": "Unit 7",
        "AddressLine2": "106 Beddington Lane",
        "AddressLine3": "Beddington",
        "PostCode": "CR0 4TB",
        "RatingValue": "4",
        "RatingKey": "fhrs_4_en-GB",
        "RatingDate": "2022-09-29",
        "LocalAuthorityCode": "529",
        "LocalAuthorityName": "Sutton",
        "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.sutton.gov.uk",
        "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "food.safety@sutton.gov.uk",
        "Scores": {
          "Hygiene": 5,
          "Structural": 5,
          "ConfidenceInManagement": 10
        },
        "SchemeType": "FHRS",
        "NewRatingPending": false,
        "Geocode": null
      },
      {
        "FHRSID": 898515,
        "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "06/00098/COM",
        "BusinessName": "A - Z Afterschool Club",
        "BusinessType": "Hospitals/Childcare/Caring Premises",
        "BusinessTypeID": 5,
        "AddressLine1": "Devonshire Primary School",
        "AddressLine2": "Devonshire Avenue",
        "AddressLine3": "Sutton",
        "PostCode": "SM2 5JL",
        "RatingValue": "5",
        "RatingKey": "fhrs_5_en-GB",
        "RatingDate": "2022-06-23",
        "LocalAuthorityCode": "529",
        "LocalAuthorityName": "Sutton",
        "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.sutton.gov.uk",
        "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "food.safety@sutton.gov.uk",
        "Scores": {
          "Hygiene": 5,
          "Structural": 5,
          "ConfidenceInManagement": 5
        },
        "SchemeType": "FHRS",
        "NewRatingPending": false,
        "Geocode": {
          "Longitude": "-0.1885",
          "Latitude": "51.353663"
        }
      },
```

Comment: remove Geocode from for loop and json and see what error it gives. also make val geocode: JSONObject nullable and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
 val geocode = establishment.optJSONObject("Geocode")
```

By using optJSONObject instead of getJSONObject, it returns null if the field is not found or if its value is null. This allows you to handle the null case appropriately without throwing an exception.